# Java 21 structured concurrency, need predictable subtask exception ordering

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-21, project-loom, structured-concurrency

I'm rather new to parallel code, and I tried to convert some code based on executors to structured concurrency, but I lost an important property that I must somehow keep.

Given the following code using structured concurrency with Java 21 preview:

```
try (var scope = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure()) {
    Subtask<Data1> d1Subtask = scope.fork(() -> getData1(input));
    Subtask<Data2> d2Subtask = scope.fork(() -> getData2(input));

    scope.join().throwIfFailed(); // [1]

    var data1 = d1Subtask.get(); // [2]
    var data2 = d2Subtask.get();

    return new Response(data1, data2);
}
```

In `[1]` an eventual first exception out of the two subtasks is thrown, and I don't want that. I need to run both tasks in parallel but I need the result of `d1Subtask` first in case it fails. In other words:

- if `d1Subtask` fails, I need to throw its exception (`d2Subtask` might be running, be successful or failed and none of it matters, exceptions from `d1Subtask` make the second task irrelevant);
- if `d1Subtask` succeeds and `d2Subtask` fail, I need the exception from `d2Subtask`;
- if both succeed, combine the results of both.

If I change it to `scope.join();` then `[2]` can fail if `d1Subtask` is not done. There is `d1Subtask.state()` but waiting for it to leave the `State.UNAVAILABLE` state seems against the idea of structured concurrency.

This can be achieved with Executors and pure `StructuredTaskScope`, but that means potentially running `d2Subtask` to completion even when the scope could be shut down and that task aborted.

Given that, is possible to modify the code above to wait for the result of `d1Subtask` in a clean, readable way? I imagined that something like `scope.join(d1Subtask)` or `d1Subtask.join()` would be the way of doing it, or maybe a different policy, if that API existed.

---

Edit: clearer explanation of the desired logic with each possible outcome.

Comment: If you don’t want the behavior of the `ShutdownOnFailure` policy, don’t use `ShutdownOnFailure`.

Comment: @Holger Yes, this is the expected behavior. Since the only other built-in policy is`ShutdownOnSuccess` (which is inadequate for me), what are my alternatives? Use `ShutdownOnFailure` and check states, implement my own policy or something else I missed?

Comment: You don’t have to decide between `ShutdownOnSuccess` and `ShutdownOnFailure`. You can simply use `new StructuredTaskScope<>()` without a special policy, then `join()` will always wait for all tasks so you can easily check whether `d1Subtask` failed before checking whether `d2Subtask` failed. You can also create a subclass implementing your own policy.

Comment: I actually haven't realized that... I always see samples with `ShutdownOn` so I didn't think that `StructuredTaskScope` was in itself useable. Kind of obvious in retrospect, after all the most basic behavior is "run all tasks to completion". Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `StructuredTaskScope` directly, without `ShutdownOnFailure`, to wait for all jobs to complete, then, you can check the results and failures in the intended order, e.g.

```java
static Response simpleApproach() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    try(var scope = new StructuredTaskScope<>()) {
        Subtask<Data1> d1Subtask = scope.fork(() -> getData1(input));
        Subtask<Data2> d2Subtask = scope.fork(() -> getData2(input));

        scope.join();

        var data1 = get(d1Subtask);
        var data2 = get(d2Subtask);

        return new Response(data1, data2);
    }
}

static <T> T get(Subtask<T> task) throws ExecutionException {
    if(task.state() == State.FAILED)
        throw new ExecutionException(task.exception());
    return task.get();
}
```

This is the simplest approach. It ensures that if both jobs failed, the exception of “data1” is propagated to the caller. The only disadvantage is that if “data1” failed before “data2”’s completion, it will wait for “data2”, without an attempt to interrupt it. This, however, may be acceptable as we’re usually not trying (too hard) to optimize the exceptional case.

---

But you can also implement your own policy. Here’s an example of a policy having a “primary job”. When other jobs failed, it will wait for the primary job’s completion, to prefer its exception if it failed too. But when the primary job failed, it will shut down immediately, trying to interrupt all other jobs and not wait for their completion:

```java
static Response customPolicy() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    try(var scope = new ShutdownOnPrimaryFailure<>()) {
        Subtask<Data1> d1Subtask = scope.forkPrimary(() -> getData1(input));
        Subtask<Data2> d2Subtask = scope.fork(() -> getData2(input));

        scope.join().throwIfFailed();

        var data1 = d1Subtask.get();
        var data2 = d2Subtask.get();

        return new Response(data1, data2);
    }
}
```

```java
class ShutdownOnPrimaryFailure<T> extends StructuredTaskScope<T> {
    private final AtomicReference<Throwable> failure = new AtomicReference<>();
    private Subtask<?> primary;

    public <U extends T> Subtask<U> forkPrimary(Callable<? extends U> task) {
        ensureOwnerAndJoined();
        Subtask<U> forked = super.fork(task);
        primary = forked;
        return forked;
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleComplete(Subtask<? extends T> subtask) {
        super.handleComplete(subtask);
        if(subtask.state() == State.FAILED) {
            if(subtask == primary) {
                failure.set(subtask.exception());
                shutdown();
            }
            else failure.compareAndSet(null, subtask.exception());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ShutdownOnPrimaryFailure<T> join() throws InterruptedException {
        super.join();
        primary = null;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ShutdownOnPrimaryFailure<T> joinUntil(Instant deadline)
        throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException {

        super.joinUntil(deadline);
        primary = null;
        return this;
    }

    public void throwIfFailed() throws ExecutionException {
        ensureOwnerAndJoined();
        Throwable t = failure.get();
        if(t != null) throw new ExecutionException(t);
    }
}
```

---

For completeness, I provide code for testing all scenarios at the end of this answer. It checks for all combinations of success and failures.

With the implemented approaches, it will print

```
  *** Original
D1 ↓  D2 →  SUCCESS      D1 D2   FAIL_FAST    D1 D2   FAIL_SLOW    D1 D2
SUCCESS:    Success       F  F   Data2 Fail    F  F   Data2 Fail    F  F
FAIL_FAST:  Data1 Fail    F  F   -             F  F   Data1 Fail    F  I
FAIL_SLOW:  Data1 Fail    F  F   Data2 Fail    I  F   -             I  F

  *** Simple
D1 ↓  D2 →  SUCCESS      D1 D2   FAIL_FAST    D1 D2   FAIL_SLOW    D1 D2
SUCCESS:    Success       F  F   Data2 Fail    F  F   Data2 Fail    F  F
FAIL_FAST:  Data1 Fail    F  F   -             F  F   Data1 Fail    F  F
FAIL_SLOW:  Data1 Fail    F  F   Data1 Fail    F  F   -             F  F

  *** Custom Policy
D1 ↓  D2 →  SUCCESS      D1 D2   FAIL_FAST    D1 D2   FAIL_SLOW    D1 D2
SUCCESS:    Success       F  F   Data2 Fail    F  F   Data2 Fail    F  F
FAIL_FAST:  Data1 Fail    F  F   -             F  F   Data1 Fail    F  I
FAIL_SLOW:  Data1 Fail    F  F   Data1 Fail    F  F   -             F  F
```

<sup>Abbrev. status: **F**inished, **I**nterrupted, or **R**unning</sup>

The issue was the scenario of D1 failing slow and D2 failing fast, in the middle of the 3rd line. The `ShutdownOnFailure` then aborted D1 (D1 status **I**nterrupted) and propagated D2’s failure. The simple approach clearly fixes it but loses the ability to fail fast when D1 failed fast (the last scenario in the 2nd line, D2 status now **F**inished). The custom policy solves the original issue while retaining the fail-fast support.

```java
public class StructuredExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        record Approach(String name, Callable<?> method) {}
        List<Approach> approaches = List.of(
            new Approach("Original", StructuredExample::originalApproach),
            new Approach("Simple", StructuredExample::simpleApproach),
            new Approach("Custom Policy", StructuredExample::customPolicy));

        for(var approach: approaches) {
            System.out.println("  *** " + approach.name());
            System.out.printf("%-12s", "D1 \u2193  D2 \u2192");
            for(Mode d2Mode: Mode.values()) System.out.printf("%-12s D1 D2   ", d2Mode);
            System.out.println();
            for(Mode d1Mode: Mode.values()) {
                System.out.printf("%-12s", d1Mode + ":");
                for(Mode d2Mode: Mode.values()) {
                    String result = "-";
                    if(d2Mode == Mode.SUCCESS || d1Mode != d2Mode) try {
                        ScopedValue.where(data1Mode, d1Mode)
                            .where(data2Mode, d2Mode)
                            .call(() -> approach.method().call());
                        result = "Success";
                    }
                    catch(ExecutionException ex) { result = ex.getCause().getMessage(); }
                    catch(Exception ex) { result = ex.getMessage(); }
                    System.out.printf("%-12s%3s%3s   ", result, d1Running.name().charAt(0), d2Running.name().charAt(0));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    // mock for the getData1 and getData2 operations, producing success or failure and recording running state

    enum Mode { SUCCESS, FAIL_FAST, FAIL_SLOW }
    enum StateDebug { RUNNING, FINISHED, INTERRUPTED; }

    static final ScopedValue<Mode> data1Mode = ScopedValue.newInstance();
    static final ScopedValue<Mode> data2Mode = ScopedValue.newInstance();

    static volatile StateDebug d1Running, d2Running;

    static Data1 getData1(Object input) throws Exception {
        return getDataImpl("Data1", data1Mode, Data1::new, s -> d1Running = s);
    }

    static Data2 getData2(Object input) throws Exception {
        return getDataImpl("Data2", data2Mode, Data2::new, s -> d2Running = s);
    }

    static <T> T getDataImpl(String which, ScopedValue<Mode> mode, Supplier<T> s, Consumer<StateDebug> c) throws Exception {
        c.accept(StateDebug.RUNNING);
        boolean interrupted = false;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            switch(mode.get()) {
                case SUCCESS: return s.get();
                case FAIL_SLOW: Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            throw new Exception(which + " Fail");
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            interrupted = true;
            c.accept(StateDebug.INTERRUPTED);
            throw ex;
        }
        finally {
            if(!interrupted) c.accept(StateDebug.FINISHED);
        }
    }

    // dummy data and types

    record Data1() {}
    record Data2() {}

    record Response(Data1 data1, Data2 data2)  {}

    static Object input;

    // the implementations

    static Response originalApproach() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        try (var scope = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure()) {
            Subtask<Data1> d1Subtask = scope.fork(() -> getData1(input));
            Subtask<Data2> d2Subtask = scope.fork(() -> getData2(input));
    
            scope.join().throwIfFailed(); // [1]
    
            var data1 = d1Subtask.get(); // [2]
            var data2 = d2Subtask.get();
    
            return new Response(data1, data2);
        }
    }

    static Response simpleApproach() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        try(var scope = new StructuredTaskScope<>()) {
            Subtask<Data1> d1Subtask = scope.fork(() -> getData1(input));
            Subtask<Data2> d2Subtask = scope.fork(() -> getData2(input));

            scope.join();

            var data1 = get(d1Subtask);
            var data2 = get(d2Subtask);

            return new Response(data1, data2);
        }
    }

    static <T> T get(Subtask<T> task) throws ExecutionException {
        if(task.state() == State.FAILED)
            throw new ExecutionException(task.exception());
        return task.get();
    }

    static Response customPolicy() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        try(var scope = new ShutdownOnPrimaryFailure<>()) {
            Subtask<Data1> d1Subtask = scope.forkPrimary(() -> getData1(input));
            Subtask<Data2> d2Subtask = scope.fork(() -> getData2(input));

            scope.join().throwIfFailed();

            var data1 = d1Subtask.get();
            var data2 = d2Subtask.get();

            return new Response(data1, data2);
        }
    }
}

class ShutdownOnPrimaryFailure<T> extends StructuredTaskScope<T> {
    private final AtomicReference<Throwable> failure = new AtomicReference<>();
    private Subtask<?> primary;

    public <U extends T> Subtask<U> forkPrimary(Callable<? extends U> task) {
        ensureOwnerAndJoined();
        Subtask<U> forked = super.fork(task);
        primary = forked;
        return forked;
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleComplete(Subtask<? extends T> subtask) {
        super.handleComplete(subtask);
        if(subtask.state() == State.FAILED) {
            if(subtask == primary) {
                failure.set(subtask.exception());
                shutdown();
            }
            else failure.compareAndSet(null, subtask.exception());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ShutdownOnPrimaryFailure<T> join() throws InterruptedException {
        super.join();
        primary = null;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ShutdownOnPrimaryFailure<T> joinUntil(Instant deadline) throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
        super.joinUntil(deadline);
        primary = null;
        return this;
    }

    public void throwIfFailed() throws ExecutionException {
        ensureOwnerAndJoined();
        Throwable t = failure.get();
        if(t != null) throw new ExecutionException(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Impressive answer! Sorry for the confusion in my initial description, but you got my scenario right here. A custom scope definitely looks like the way for complex cases. I also posted another answer here with nested scopes after taking a look at your code.

Comment: Perfect implementation of idea of subclassing to define _custom_ on-fail/on-success behavior! 1) Is check on failed status necessary in `get(Subtask<T> task)` method? Does not `throwifFailed` guarantee that the point of calling `get(Subtask<T> task)` can only be reached when both tasks completed successfully? 2) Is ordering of `forkPrimary` in front of other `forks`'s, achieved by `ensureOwnerAndJoined` call in `forkPrimary` method, necessary? Does not logic, implemented in `handleComplete` override, correctly handle the cases when `forkPrimary` follows other `fork`s, not visa versa?

Comment: @igor.zh 1) If you are referring to the `simpleApproach()`, it does not use `throwIfFailed()` because this method does not exist on the base class `StructuredTaskScope`. I added the `get(Subtask<T> task)` method specifically to have a method behaving like `Future.get` while `SubTask` behaves differently. 2) It’s not strictly necessary for a single round but the design of the class allows multiple rounds, i.e. after `join()`, you can start a new round with one primary task and an arbitrary number of other subtasks. I wanted to be close to the other policies which also support multiple rounds.

Answer (score 0):

What `ShutdownOnFailure` subclass of `StructuredTaskScope` eseentially does it attempts to stop the other running `SubTask`s (or prevent them from running if they haven't yet started) if at least one of the `SubTask`s threw an exception, i.e *failed*. If, like the question specifies

> d2Subtask might be running, be successful or failed and none of it matters,

and there is no need to stop/interrupt `d2Subtask`, then the usage of `ShutdownOnFailure` is not justified.
Instead, the selective exception analysis, requested by the question

> if d1Subtask fails ... throw its exception; if d2Subtask fails, throw the exception from d2Subtask

can be achieved by the usage of base `StructuredTaskScope` and a subsequent to `join` analysis of both statuses and exceptions, if any.

```
try (var scope = new StructuredTaskScope<>()) {
    Subtask<Data1> d1Subtask = scope.fork(() -> getData1(input1)); 
    Subtask<Data2> d2Subtask = scope.fork(() -> getData2(input2));
    scope.join();
        
    if (d1Subtask.state() == State.FAILED) {
        throw d1Subtask.exception();
    }
    if (d2Subtask.state() == State.FAILED) {
        throw d2Subtask.exception();
    }
    if (d1Subtask.state() != State.SUCCESS || d2Subtask.state() != State.SUCCESS) {
        throw new InternalError();
    }
        
    var data1 = d1Subtask.get(); // [2]
    var data2 = d2Subtask.get();

    return new Response(data1, data2);
}
```

Note that with the above code the lines

```
var data1 = d1Subtask.get(); // [2]
var data2 = d2Subtask.get();
```

are guaranteed to execute without exception.

There is an important difference between this and the accepted solution: the former does not shutdown the scope and allows the `d2Subtask` to complete even if `d1Subtask` fails while the latter in this case shuts down the scope (which only means that the scope will attempt to stop/interrupt the `d2Subtask` thread and give up if the thread is irresponsive). The OP didn't specify if termination of `d2Subtask` in a case of failure of `d1Subtask` is required, just said: "none of it matters". If this means that `d2Subtask` can be altogether left alone, then the above solution completely satisfies the OP's requirements; if this means that `d2Subtask` must be immediately terminated, then only accepted answer, which overrides `handleComplete`, can be satisfactory.

Comment: [The contract of `join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/StructuredTaskScope.html#join()) is “*Wait for all subtasks started in this task scope to finish **or** the task scope to shut down.*” So when using `ShutdownOnFailure` which will shut down on the first failure, it is not guaranteed that all subtasks finished. You can avoid this by using a direct instance of `StructuredTaskScope` instead of the specialized subclasses but then, there is no `throwIfFailed()` method.

Comment: @Holger, edited correspondingly. Please see if this coincides with your vision.

Comment: The program logic is correct but might not fit the OP’s requirement. When `throwIfFailed()` throws, it might be an exception thrown by `d2Subtask` while `d1Subtask` has not completed. As far as I understood, the OP wants to wait for the completion of `d1Subtask` in that case, to check whether it failed too to ensure to throw `d1Subtask`’s exception when both failed.

Comment: @Holger, yes, you are right. When the OP recently clarified what exactly he wants to achieve, the solution seems to be even easier - I updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the feedback from @Holger, I thought of another approach using nested scopes, which I include here for completeness sake:

```
static Response nestedScopes() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    try(var scope1 = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure()) {
        Subtask<Data1> d1Subtask = scope1.fork(() -> getData1(input));

        try(var scope2 = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure()) {
            Subtask<Data2> d2Subtask = scope2.fork(() -> getData2(input));

            scope1.join().throwIfFailed();
            scope2.join().throwIfFailed();

            var data1 = d1Subtask.get();
            var data2 = d2Subtask.get();

            return new Response(data1, data2);
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is an advisable approach. The result is the same as @Holger's custom scope; it's less code, but probably would become hard to follow as complexity, subtasks and relationship grows, and in that case a custom scope is probably still a better approach.

Comment: That seems to work, but isn't equivalent to @Holger's _simple_ approach? This seems to be an unnecessary complication. `ShutdownOnFailure` will shutdown other tasks if one fails, but what is the usage of it if there is only one task in a scope?

Comment: @igor.zh No, his _Simple_ approach will cause an exception from `d2Subtask` to be thrown if that finishes first. My approach above should be equivalent to his _Custom Policy_, which always prioritizes the result of `d1Subtask` first even if `d2Subtask` fails first, and that matches my original requirement.

Comment: Honestly, don't see how his simple approach will cause an exception from `d2Subtask` to be thrown if that finishes first - if it checks `d1Subtask` first. But @Holger knows better his approaches. No, it does not look to me that your approach is equivalent to his _custom_ one as yours does not attempt to shutdown the second subtask if first fails - the main point of thus custom thing. This is discussed in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78076019/2366397)..

Comment: My bad. His _Simple_ approach will be equivalent because of the `get(Subtask)` method that I missed... yet _Simple_ is still slightly less optimized as it waits for the completion of `d2Subtask` regardless of the first task, as exposed by @Holger. This caveat is addressed in his _Custom Policy_ and should be in my code above too, if I tested properly. And about not attempting to shutdown, it actually does: remember that scope objects are `AutoCloseable`. This is in the docs of `close`: `This method first shuts down the task scope (as if by invoking the shutdown method).`

Comment: Agree with your analysis of  _Simple_ vs _Custom_. As for shutdown, `close` method does not do anything in all approaches including all three @Holger's, yours and mine (other than switching scope's `state` to `CLOSED`), because all threads are finished at the time this method is called. In all 5 cases the entire scope will be eventually shut down anyway, but _Custom_ shuts down `d2Subtask` as early as possible -  when `d1Subtask` fails.