# How to customize the Shutdown policy of Java 21's Structured Concurrency API?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-21, structured-concurrency

I have the following use case where I want to retrieve multiple error status information for a device from multiple data sources. I want to terminate all tasks immediately and return the error status to the main task if any of the statuses is true. How can I achieve this? Here is my query logic:

```java
try (var scope = new StructuredTaskScope<>()) {
            scope.fork(()->posRepo.findInspectionByUnitId(unitId));
            scope.fork(()->posRepo.findEventOfFireByUnitId(unitId));
            scope.fork(()->faultRepo.findGeneralErrorByUnitId(unitId));
            scope.fork(()->ardInfRepo.findArdModeByUnitId(unitId));
            scope.fork(()->ardInfRepo.findArdPowerStatusByUnitId(unitId));
            scope.fork(()->ardInfRepo.findArdModeByUnitId(unitId));
            // Once a task return true, close all remaining tasks,and return the  signal:"true" to main task;
            scope.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

```java
public interface ElePosRepo extends CrudRepository<PositionInformation,Integer> {

    Optional<Boolean> findInspectionByUnitId(Integer unitId);
    Optional<Boolean> findEventOfFireByUnitId(Integer unitId);
}
```

I expect that when a subtask returns true, all other subtasks within the task group should be immediately terminated. If all subtasks return false or are empty, the main task should return false after completing all subtasks.

Comment: You may subclass `StructuredTaskScope` to implement your own policy. You may check out [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78073182/2711488) for an example of a custom policy implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 21 structured concurrency, need predictable subtask exception ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78073182/java-21-structured-concurrency-need-predictable-subtask-exception-ordering)

Comment: Not yet. I am new to Java concurrent development, so the content in this answer is a little difficult for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ShutdownOnFirstTrue extends StructuredTaskScope<Optional<Boolean>> {
    
    private volatile boolean succeeded;
    
    @Override
    protected void handleComplete(Subtask<? extends Optional<Boolean>> subtask) {
        if (subtask.state() == State.SUCCESS) {
            subtask.get().filter((b) -> b.booleanValue()).ifPresent( (b) -> {
                succeeded = true;
                shutdown();
            });
        }
    }
    
    public boolean isSucceeded() {
        return succeeded;
    }

}
```

and `isSucceeded` should be accessed after `join` completes

```
try (var scope = new ShutdownOnFirstTrue()) {
    scope.fork...
    scope.fork...
    scope.fork...
    scope.join();
    boolean succeeded = scope.isSucceeded();
}
```

but instead of relying on the haphazard solution to equally haphazard (for example, you didn't specify a behavior on exceptions, thrown by subtasks) requirements, expressed in the question, I'd suggest to learn `handleComplete` overriding technique, it is recommended for definition of custom behavior, was introduced right in `StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure` and `StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnSuccess` and @Holger gave another excellent example [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78080818/2366397).

Some technical details:

- The class is not reentrant with next round of `fork`s after `join`. To achieve it, either have a (re)setter for `succeeded` field or override both `join`s like @Holger did, the second way is more elegant, but it is a bit more prone to errors as it might silently fail if next version will add third `join`; (but would like to have `joinImpl` protected in next version or have some kind of `joinCompleted` placeholder in the base class).
- `shutdown` is not guarded against concurrent invocations, as I believe that `implShutdown` already does this, so I found a guarding in `ShutdownOnSuccess.handleComplete` excessive.
- there is no any special action provisioned on an exception, thrown by a subtask. It will be just silently consumed. To handle an exception if it is expected please see if the result of `StructuredTaskScope.Subtask` in overridden `handleComplete` method is `Subtask.State.FAILED` and act accordingly. The good example of such handling is stock `ShutdownOnFailure.handleComplete`, `ShutdownOnFailure` is a final class, though, and cannot be reused for your purpose. Once again, due to the lack of clearly pronounced system requirements the `ShutdownOnFirstTrue` above is only a hint, not a fully working tool.